# Runtime crash: nativescript APP crashes on a real device but runs on any simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, runtime, nativescript, nativescript-vue

The app runs on a simulator of XCode but once executed on a real device, it displays a black or white screen and stops at [runtime executeModule:@"./"] in main.m file. I have to manually stop the execution by clicking on the Xcode button to free up the phone.
Nativescript: 5.4.0
IOS: 12.3.1
Mac OS: Mojave

**package.JSON**

```
    {
  "name": "food-med_v01",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A native application built with NativeScript-Vue",
  "author": "XXXXXX",
  "license": "MIT",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.food_med_01",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.4.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nativescript-background-http": "^3.4.0",
    "nativescript-camera": "^4.5.0",
    "nativescript-gradient": "^2.0.1",
    "nativescript-http-formdata": "^1.6.0",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^6.2.0",
    "nativescript-socketio": "^3.2.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.4",
    "nativescript-toasty": "^1.3.0",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^6.3.2",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^4.3.0",
    "nativescript-vue": "^2.0.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^5.0.2",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^5.4.2",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-traverse": "6.26.0",
    "babel-types": "6.26.0",
    "babylon": "6.18.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "cli": "^1.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~3.0.0",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.24.1",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-worker-loader": "~0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "raw-loader": "~0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "~2.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.2.6",
    "webpack": "^4.33.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "~2.13.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-sources": "~1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried updating your `tns-core-modules` ?

Comment: and you `nativescript-ui-sidedrawer` is also very old. try updating them both

Comment: What you are exactly doing on application launch? Can you share some error logs?  Also as mentioned by @Narendra I doubt iOS runtime v5.4.1 will be compatible with tns-core-modules v5.0.2. Try updating the dependencies to their latest.

Comment: and it could be hmr issue as well try `tns build ios --no-hmr`

Comment: Hi everyone. @Narendra Yes I updated the dependencies but still the problem persists. Please find the device and xcode logs at this url (They were too long to be just pasted over here): [https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dyy7t6qAhNY_K0kJUJyCQsubDQvziKJZ]                                           _tns run is --provision nameOfProvision_ is working well now